# Why does rake jasmine:ci load a different(failing) asset pipeline than rake jasmine does in rails?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, jasmine

All my jasmine tests are passing in chrome after running rake:jasmine, however I'm getting many errors similar to:

```
TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'function (event) {
this.quickPicks(event);
```

}.bind(this)') in http://localhost:33351/assets/date_picker.self.js?body=1?body=true (line 15)
          TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'function (event) {
    this.quickPicks(event);
  }.bind(this)')

When I run rake jasmine:ci

I think this could be related to the rails asset pipeline not loading properly in the jasmine:ci command.  I've tried adjusting my application.js file but nothing seems to work.

I'm using: 
rails 4.2.0, 
sprockets 3.7.1, 
jasmine 2.3.1, 
jasmine-core 2.3.4, 
jasmine-jquery-rails 2.0.3

Answer (score 0):

So, I'm not sure what the problem was, but it appears it was a bug with an older version of jasmine and phantomjs. When I ran bundle update jasmine, they both updated (jasmine to 2.8.0 and phantomjs from 1.9.8.0 to 2.1.1.0), and the errors disappeared. Unfortunately, problems with loading fixtures came along with the update, but it seems easier to resolve...